How to fix badly scratched wall? (Paint scraped off)
I badly scratched my wall the other day... how would one fix this? It seems very deep and past the top coat.
Do I just bring paint chips to the store to match the color, then paint over it (with primer applied beforehand)? ...Do I have to buy a whole can of primer and paint just for this one scratch?




Was this recently painted? You may know, paint takes up to a month to fully cure and reach its target hardness. The considerations for touch up depend how old this paint is.

Is this paint over wallpaper?

Thank you Fredric, I was thinking that it might be different since it seems like a deeper scratch!
@AdamO it's been around 1 year since the paint was applied! I'm not sure if there was wallpaper but I think there isn't..

Take a razor knife with a new blade and cut off the paint and paper that are hanging there.
Use the razor knife to trim off the edges that are rough. You don't need to cut deep, just through the paint and paper.
Fill the gouge with General purpose compound. Use a 4 inch taping knife. Let the compound spread far over the boundaries of the gouge. (A couple of inches in all directions). Let it dry.
If after it drys there are cracks, it means the gouge was pretty deep and you need to fill with a second coat of compound. Let it dry.
When all is dry, don't sand, wipe with a damp sponge.  Concentrate on the edges.  The sponge will wipe the dry wall compound but let the wall paint remain You will see some tiny bumps of the painted surface of the wall coming through the edges of the patch.  That is good. When you see the spots and no hard edges, stop wiping.
You have a light orange-peel texture on the wall. You need to try to reproduce that with Water based spray orange -peel texture  This is the trick. It takes practice.  Adjust the can to a fine spray and test on cardboard or scrap  plywood. Beware the first spray from a new can is like a big sneeze. Don't spray on the wall to start. Adjust the spray pattern to closely match your wall.  Spray in a circular motion about 30 inches from the wall. Extend the spray pattern about 6 inches or more over your patch. ( you will need to put down drop cloths and cover anything within 5 feet of where you are spraying.
When the texture is done. let it dry for at least 24 hrs, then you can prime and paint.  ( Manufacturer,may tell you it is ok to paint in less time, but don't chance it. If not cured, a wet paint roller can pull the texture off the wall.)
You can get paint matched in quarts. Some places will make "samples" of colors in pints. Prime and when dry paint 2 coats.

It looks like you have even torn up the paper on the drywall. If this paint was fully cured, my process would be to:

Gently sand the area using various sanding pads. start as low as 60 and up to 300 grit over 3 passes. The goal is to create a "bowl" for new paint.

Once a bowl is achieved, fill the area with a patching plaster.

When patching plaster dries, sand the area lightly to blend into old wall, then apply a primer. For primer, use an oil based primer, even the style in a spraycan. This replaces the drywall paper which allows the moisture and air to pass through the wall at an even rate, eliminating the risk of bubbling (this is my DIY perspective and may be superstitious, others chime in). Feather the edges.

Once the primer is dried, lightly sand the area and apply a top coat. Normally I would suggest to sand between coats, but it seems like this wall has several layers of paint that were never sanded between coats, so apply another coat thickly using crusty paint near the top of the can to emulate the orange peel-ish texture.



Thank you! I think I'll gather some supplies to do this - I have some sanding supplies so perhaps just a small drywall patch kit for the patching plaster, then hopefully a small amount of primer and top coat

@play150 good luck. I should have mentioned, try not to increase the depth of the gouge as you sand, i.e. don't sand into the drywall or paper at all if it can be avoided. You are merely spreading out the damange into a smooth, nonnoticeable concave depression.
